# display get_pages result on several pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following bit of php to get a page to display the content of its children pages.
I want to show only the first 10 results and then a 'show more' button.
I tried replacing post_content by post_excerpt (L6) but that didn't work. What am I missing?

```
<?php
    $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
        $content = $page->post_content;
        if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
            continue;

        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
        <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    <?php
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through a for loop and set the length of the loop to 10? Or, using array_slice if your data comes back as an array of pages? Not sure if I am understanding your problem.

Comment: Well but in this case I limit the results to the first 10 results but there's no button to show the rest of the results, no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `get_pages` about the page number you desire.  However, looking at [the get_pages documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) I don't see any explicit page number parameter; instead, I suspect you'll want the `offset` argument instead.  Consider trying:

```
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc', 'offset' => ( $posts_per_page * $paged ) ) );
```

The `'offset' => ( $posts_per_page * ( $page_number - 1) )` calculation multiplies the global `$posts_per_page` (defined in your Reading Settings) against a `$page_number` you supply somehow.  The page number is decremented by one because you want to start from the specified point; if you had 10 posts per page and wanted to start on the second page, you'd want the first post you show to be index #10 (using a zero-indexed list), and show through #19.

How you choose to identify which page is requested is left to your discretion, but one option would be to provide a query string argument (e.g. `pagenumber=3`) and reference that before calling `get_pages` by stating:

```
$page_number = is_numeric( $_GET['pagenumber']) ? $_GET['pagenumber'] : 0 )
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I'm not trying to split the results in pages and then calling a specific one. The page I created is very long and the loading time is an issue. I'm trying to display only part of the result and then allow the user to click a button at the bottom of the page to see more.